# How can I remove horizontal lines on a phase plot for a pendulum?

Tags: differential-equations

I am attempting to do a phase plot for a driven,damped pendulum.  When the angle wraps from Pi to -Pi or -Pi to Pi I get a horizontal line on the plot. I would like to remove these lines as they mask the structure that is evident when plotting chaotic orbits. The function sss[t] performs the angle wrap and uses the piecewise function. Also I wanted to post the plot along with this question but could not find information on how to do it.

```
s = NDSolve[{\[Theta]''[t] + .5 \[Theta]'[t] + Sin[\[Theta][t]] == 
    1.35 Sin[2/3 t], \[Theta][0] == Pi/4, \[Theta]'[0] == 0}, {\[Theta],
    \[Theta]'}, {t, 0, 10000}];

 ss[t_] := Flatten[{\[Theta][t]} /. s]

 sss[t_] := Piecewise[{{Mod[ss[t][[1]], 2 Pi] - 2 Pi, 
            Mod[ss[t][[1]], 2 Pi] > Pi && ss[t][[1]] >= 0}, {Mod[ss[t][[1]], 
            2 Pi], Mod[ss[t][[1]], 2 Pi] < Pi && 
            ss[t][[1]] >= 0}, {-(Mod[-ss[t][[1]], 2 Pi] - 2 Pi), 
            Mod[-ss[t][[1]], 2 Pi] > Pi && 
            ss[t][[1]] < 0}, {-(Mod[-ss[t][[1]], 2 Pi]), 
            Mod[-ss[t][[1]], 2 Pi] < Pi && ss[t][[1]] < 0}, {ss[t][[1]], -Pi
            <= ss[t][[1]] <= Pi}}]

 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{sss[t], \[Theta]'[t]} /. s], {t, 800, 1000}, 
 PlotRange -> 3]
```

Comment: Please learn how to upvote and downvote question and answers!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You need to use `Exclusions` with conditions on `t`.  You need to find the values of `t` where the function is discontinuous.  Using `NDSolveValue` should also simplify things.  Don't return both `theta` and `theta'` from `NDSolveValue`.  `theta` is sufficient, you can take the derivative later.  See also if the third argument of `Mod` can simplify your `Piecewise`.

Comment: All of the answers below were extremely instructional. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation, I managed to use `Exclusions` to produce the following.

```
ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate[{sss[t], \[Theta]'[t]} /. s],
  {t, 799, 809},
  Exclusions -> {sss[t] == 0}
  ]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: This is how it *should* be done, but it's just unrealistically slow even with the radically reduced parameter range in your test. With the original range of `t`, I didn't have the patience to wait for a result... (+1) anyway.

Answer (score 3):

For a phase plot where one axis is an angle, you generally may not have a self-retracing curve, so you can't always count on being able to get a complete picture by just trimming the unnecessary repetitions of the curve - there may be no repetitions in $\theta'$ even if $\theta$ wraps around.

So here is a way to get the angle to fall within the fundamental interval $[-\pi, \,\pi]$ while not throwing away any part of the `ParametricPlot`:

```
s = First@
   NDSolve[{θ''[t] + .5 θ'[t] + Sin[θ[t]] == 
      1.35 Sin[2/3 t], θ[0] == Pi/4, θ'[0] == 
      0}, θ, {t, 0, 10000}];
plt = ParametricPlot[{θ[t], θ'[t]} /. s, {t, 800, 1000}];

remap[x_List] := Apply[{Mod[#1, 2 Pi, -Pi], #2} &, 
  SplitBy[x, Quotient[#[[1]], 2 Pi, Pi] &], {2}]

Show[plt /. Line[xx_] :> Line@remap[xx], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1.1 Pi, 1.1 Pi}, {-2, 2}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: wrapped]

In `plt`, the `ParametricPlot` generates a single long line which contains the unwanted jumps. I use post-processing to get rid of those:

In `plt`, I find the contents of the `Line`, and modify them using`remap`.

The function `remap` does the `Mod` operation with an offset specified in the third argument, as mentioned by Szabolcs in the comment. But before doing so, I use [`SplitBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html) to divide the content of the line according to the [`Quotient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quotient.html) (the counterpart of `Mod`) of the $\theta$ entry divided by $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Undoubtedly, there are elegant ways to solve this problem.  A quick and dirty approach is first to look at the line segments that make up the plot.

```
plt = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{sss[t], \[Theta]'[t]} /. s], {t, 800, 1000}, 
 PlotRange -> 3];
Cases[plt, Line[{z__}] -> z, {0, Infinity}]
```

You will see that there are 3065 elements, enough to trace your curve many times over.  Identify the beginning and end points of one cycle, here `4 ;; 149`, and plot only that portion.

```
tem = Cases[plt, Line[{z__}] -> z, {0, Infinity}][[4 ;; 149]]; 
plt /. Line[{z__}] :> Line[tem]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, although

```
r = First@NDSolve[{θ''[t] + .5 θ'[t] + Sin[θ[t]] == 1.35 Sin[2/3 t], 
    θ[0] == Pi/4, θ'[0] == 0}, θ, {t, 0, 10000}];
ParametricPlot[{Mod[θ[t], 2 Pi, -Pi], θ'[t]} /. r, {t, 980, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

produces the undesired line,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

the simple change

```
s = θ /. r;
ParametricPlot[{Mod[s[t], 2 Pi, -Pi], s'[t]}, {t, 980, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

does not.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The more compact

```
s = NDSolveValue[{θ''[t] + .5 θ'[t] + Sin[θ[t]] == 1.35 Sin[2/3 t], 
    θ[0] == Pi/4, θ'[0] == 0}, θ, {t, 0, 10000}]
ParametricPlot[{Mod[s[t], 2 Pi, -Pi], s'[t]}, {t, 980, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

also works well.