# Plot of the Mod of NDSolve solutions sometimes connects discontinuous jumps

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

UPDATE 2: Fixed in V11!

UPDATE: The answers given are informative, and provide a workaround which has been given in other posts, but is unfortunately not very efficient. There still seems to be a lack of deeper understanding of the origin of the problem, and of a solution which might address the problem more directly and/or efficiently. So I'm choosing to keep the question open in the hopes of still receiving such an answer.

---

I've had trouble plotting periodic solutions to `NDSolve` properly. By periodic I mean solutions that I have modified with `Mod[ ]` (after receiving them from `NDSolve`) so that they're subjected to periodic boundary conditions.

The trouble is that sometimes when the solution "jumps" from one side of the plot to the other (due to the periodic boundary conditions), the plot draws a straight line from one point to the next, crossing the entirety of the graph.

After eliminating other known causes of this, I've found that it is reproducible only for particularly "difficult" solutions. In my case, the equations being solved have to be several coupled nonlinear equations, and the length in time of the solution must be past some (inconsistent) threshold.

Example:

The following code solves for position and momentum of a particle's motion in 2D space, using `{x'[t] == 2 px[t], px'[t] == Sin[x[t]], y'[t] == 2 py[t], py'[t] == Sin[y[t]]}` with simple initial conditions, going from `t=0` to some `t=tmax`. It then plots two forms of the solution:

1. The spatial solution made periodic on a rectangle by using `Mod[ ]` on x and y
2. The spatial solution made periodic on a diamond shape by using `Piecewise` on x and y (the details are a little subtle but unnecessary for this question)

Note that the details of this example are likely irrelevant to the problem, but since the problem requires a somewhat complex case for it to occur, it was hard to simplify any further.

Here's the code:

```
x=1;

Clear[x1, px1, y1, py1, s1, x, px, y, py]

tmax = 40;

s1 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 2 px[t], px'[t] == Sin[x[t]], y'[t] == 2 py[t],
     py'[t] == Sin[y[t]], x[0] == 0, px[0] == 1, y[0] == π, 
     py[0] == 1}, {x, px, y, py}, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxSteps -> 10000000][[1]];

(*x1 etc. are solutions with a rectangular boundary*)
x1[t_] = Mod[Evaluate[x[t] /. s1], 4 π, -2 π];
px1[t_] = Evaluate[px[t] /. s1];
y1[t_] = Mod[Evaluate[y[t] /. s1], 4 π/Sqrt[3]];
py1[t_] = Evaluate[py[t] /. s1];

(*x etc. are solutions on a diamond boundary*)
x[t_] = Piecewise[{{x1[t] - 2 π, 
     y1[t] > 4 π/Sqrt[3] - x1[t]/Sqrt[3]},(*move NE corner*)
    {x1[t] - 2 π, y1[t] < x1[t]/Sqrt[3]},(*move SE corner*)
    {x1[t] + 2 π, y1[t] > 4 π/Sqrt[3] + x1[t]/Sqrt[3]},(*move NW corner*)
    {x1[t] + 2 π, y1[t] < -x1[t]/Sqrt[3]}},(*move SW corner*)
     x1[t]];

px[t_] = px1[t];

y[t_] = Piecewise[{{y1[t] - 2 π/Sqrt[3], 
     y1[t] > 4 π/Sqrt[3] - x1[t]/Sqrt[3]},(*move NE corner*)
    {y1[t] + 2 π/Sqrt[3], y1[t] < x1[t]/Sqrt[3]},(*move SE corner*)
    {y1[t] - 2 π/Sqrt[3], y1[t] > 4 π/Sqrt[3] + x1[t]/Sqrt[3]},(*move NW corner*)
    {y1[t] + 2 π/Sqrt[3], y1[t] < -x1[t]/Sqrt[3]}},(*move SW corner*)
     y1[t]];

py[t_] = py1[t];

modplot = 
 ParametricPlot[{x1[t], y1[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0], AspectRatio -> 1/Sqrt[3], 
  PlotRange -> {{-2 π, 2 π}, {0, 4 π/Sqrt[3]}}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Rectangular Periodic BC's, t=40"]

diamondplot = 
  ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0], AspectRatio -> 1/Sqrt[3], 
   PlotRange -> {{-2 π, 2 π}, {0, 4 π/Sqrt[3]}}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Diamond Periodic BC's, t=40"];

diamondbg = {Plot[x/Sqrt[3], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
   Plot[-x/Sqrt[3], {x, -2 π, 0}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]],
   Plot[4 π/Sqrt[3] - x/Sqrt[3], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]], 
   Plot[4 π/Sqrt[3] + x/Sqrt[3], {x, -2 π, 0}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]};

Show[diamondplot, diamondbg]
```

When `tmax` is low (I used `tmax = 40` here), the plots look the way they should, like this:

[image]

[image]

But when `tmax` is high (for me `tmax=80` did the trick), the latter graph gets some inconvenient black lines strewn across it:

[image]

[image]

The lines seem to be `NDSolve` choosing to line-connect all the points in the solution, thereby connecting parts of the solution that should be physically separated by the boundary conditions. And this seems to happen once the solution passes a certain (unclear) level of complexity. This threshold of complexity is also inconsistent, as I sometimes find that when using `tmax = 60`, one run will produce the lines while the next run (with nothing altered) will not.

(As a guess for why this alteration happens at all, I have noticed that in general some `NDSolve` solutions have outright gaps where the solution path is briefly disconnected, so this may be an attempt to self-correct those kinds of errors.)

So my question is: How can I force `NDSolve` to never produce these lines? Is there an option that can be set for this?

Comment: `NDSolve` is not the problem. It's the plotting.

Comment: But why would a plot function care about the total length of a solution (tmax = 80) when I only tell it to plot a fraction of the solution ({t, 0, 5})?

Comment: With `tmax=40` try `ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 5.1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0, 0], AspectRatio -> 1/Sqrt[3], 
 PlotRange -> {{-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 4 \[Pi]/Sqrt[3]}}]`

Comment: This is the result ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2f42J.png).The difference is the interval partitions that `PLot` is using

Comment: I don't get the same result as you for that command. But if it is the fault of the plot function, could you suggest how to modify its behavior?

Comment: The answers to Question [78825](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78825/1063) may provide some useful insights.

Comment: @Max  With Mathematica 10.2, I cannot reproduce belisarius' result.  But, I also cannot reproduce your fourth plot either.  It looks just like your second plot.  What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I'm using v.10.1 student edition. Have you tried cranking up tmax even further? It's possible the threshold for the change depends on computation time, which can of course vary between computers. Also, I've been looking at Question 78825, but with no success yet.

Comment: @Max  I can reproduce the problem with `tmax = 400`.  This is surprising, because the issue is very unlikely to be associated with `NDSolve`, as march stated.  I shall take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I agree the whole thing is surprising -- that's why I'm here! Thanks, look forward to any thoughts you might have.

Comment: I tried to make the title more succinct -- if I erred, you can roll back the edit.  (IMO, shorter titles that point out the main problem attract more interest.)

Comment: I like the new title better, thanks!

Comment: I think this problem has gone away in V11.  Can you confirm it?

Comment: Confirmed! I tried it up to t=40000 and got no discontinuous jumps. Thanks, I'll choose your updated answer as the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** This problem seems to have been fixed in V11.

---

This question is related to my answer to [Help remove annoying vertical lines in a piecewise plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88960/help-remove-annoying-vertical-lines-in-a-piecewise-plot/88987#88987).

The discontinuity processing is done under a time constraint of `0.2` seconds.  When `NDSolve` is run for over a longer interval, the results take up more memory and take longer for `Plot` to process.  At some point, the time exceeds the constraint and `Plot` skips the automatic `Exclusions` processing.

Using [bbgodfrey's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey) simplified code, with `tmax` set to `40` and `300` resp., here are the timings for analyzing the exclusions:

```
foo40 = Visualization`VisualizationDiscontinuities[x2[t], {t}]; // Timing
(*  0.0392754  *)

foo300 = Visualization`VisualizationDiscontinuities[x2[t], {t}]; // Timing
(*  0.301278  *)
```

As you can see, the larger solution takes much longer.  Here are the sizes of the solutions:

```
ByteCount@ {x2[t], y2[t]}   (* tmax = 40 *)
(*  397784  *)

ByteCount@ {x2[t], y2[t]}   (* tmax = 300 *)
(*  2739256  *)
```

A possible, but slow, workaround is

```
Plot[{x2[t], y2[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> foo300[[All, 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the discontinuities of `x2` and `y2` were different, you would have to compute each and join them.

*Edit: Addendum*

Note that for `ParametricPlot`, the call is on the whole parametrization:

```
Visualization`VisualizationDiscontinuities[{x2[t], y2[t]}, {t}]
```

`Plot` calls `VisualizationDiscontinuities` separately.  In all cases, the time constraint is `0.2`.  While the call on the whole parametrization took only a little longer than a call on a single component, it is nonetheless probably the reason why results are difficult to replicate, since the time a computation takes might vary from machine to machine.

Comment: Indeed, a very informative explanation (+1}, probably explaining why readers were obtaining different answers for the same value of `tmax`.  Where can I find more information on the `Visualization` package?  Searching with Google, I came up empty-handed.  Incidentally, I found that `ParametricPlot` encounters difficulties detecting discontinuities at smaller values of `tmax` than `Plot` does.  Any idea why?

Comment: @bbgodfrey `ParametricPlot` calls ``Visualization`VisualizationDiscontinuities[{x2[t], y2[t]}, {t}]``, while `Plot` makes a separate call for each function. Each has the same time constraint. So in `ParametricPlot`, there is (at least) twice as much work to do to analyze the discontinuities.  --  I don't think any of it is documented. I've learned it from `Trace`, spelunking, and semi-informed guessing from things like ``?Vis*`*``.

Answer (score 9):

As a starting point for addressing this rather difficult question, it makes sense to omit as much code as possible while still reproducing the issue.

```
tmax = 40;
{x0, y0} = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 2 px[t], px'[t] == Sin[x[t]], y'[t] == 2 py[t],
     py'[t] == Sin[y[t]], x[0] == 0, px[0] == 1, y[0] == π, 
     py[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}, StartingStepSize -> 10^-4];
x1[t_] = Mod[x0[t], 4 π, -2 π];
y1[t_] = Mod[y0[t], 4 π/Sqrt[3]];
x2[t_] = x1[t] - 2 π Piecewise[{{1, ! (4 π - x1[t] > Sqrt[3] y1[t] > x1[t])},
    {-1, ! (4 π + x1[t] > Sqrt[3] y1[t] > -x1[t])}}];
y2[t_] = y1[t] - 2 π/Sqrt[3] Piecewise[{{1, ! (4 π - Sqrt[3] y1[t] > x1[t] > 
    Sqrt[3] y1[t] - 4 π)}, {-1, ! (Sqrt[3] y1[t] > x1[t] > -Sqrt[3] y1[t])}}];
```

This abbreviated code differs from that in the question in one substantive way.  `StartingStepSize -> 10^-4` has been added to the options of `NDSolveValue` to assure that the temporal grid for small `t` is independent of `tmax`.  Although this change has no direct effect on the issue at hand, it is essential for the comparisons made later in this answer.  To see that the code in this answer produces substantially the same results as those in the question, use

```
ParametricPlot[{x1[t], y1[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
                AspectRatio -> 1/Sqrt[3], PlotRange -> {{-2 π, 2 π}, {0, 4 π/Sqrt[3]}}]
```

which reproduces the first plot in the question, and

```
ParametricPlot[{x2[t], y2[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
                AspectRatio -> 1/Sqrt[3], PlotRange -> {{-2 π, 2 π}, {0, 4 π/Sqrt[3]}}]
```

which reproduces the second plot in the question, but without the diamond-shaped boarder.  Likewise, creating these same plots for `tmax = 300` (for instance) yields the third and fourth plots in the question, again without the diamond-shaped boarder.  However, it is more informative to consider, instead,

```
Plot[{x2[t], y2[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

which for `tmax = 40` yields

[image]

and for `tmax = 300` yields

[image]

`Plot` should, and usually does, eliminate the vertical lines at function discontinuities but does not do so here at `tmax = 300` and other large values of `tmax`.  Adding the option `Exclusions -> True` in `Plot` does not help.  Of course, setting `Exclusions` to the list of `t` values at which the discontinuities occur would eliminate the vertical lines, but doing so does not address the issue of why `Plot` eliminate the vertical lines for some `tmax` and not others.

The obvious hypothesis is that `x0` and `y0`, and the quantities derived from them, differ in the plot domain, `0 <= t <= 5` for different `tmax`.  To test this supposition, we first compare the actual values of `x0` and `y0` computed by `NDSolveValue` on the temporal grid `0 <= t <= 5.66`.  (For convenience, `x0`, etc are labeled `x0b` for `tmax = 40` in what follows, while `x0`, etc are the quantities for `tmax = 300`.)

```
Transpose[{Flatten[x0["Grid"]], Flatten[x0["ValuesOnGrid"]], 
    Flatten[y0["ValuesOnGrid"]]}][[1 ;; 120]] == 
 Transpose[{Flatten[x0b["Grid"]], Flatten[x0b["ValuesOnGrid"]], 
    Flatten[y0b["ValuesOnGrid"]]}][[1 ;; 120]]
(* True *)
```

They are the same for `0 <= t <= 5.66`.  In fact, more information lurks in the `InterpolatingFunction`s produced by `NDSolveValue`,

```
x0b[[4, 3]][[1 ;; 240]] == x0[[4, 3]][[1 ;; 240]]
y0b[[4, 3]][[1 ;; 240]] == y0[[4, 3]][[1 ;; 240]]
(* True *)
(* True *)
```

But these too are the same.  Evaluating the functions themselves at thousands of points also uncovers no differences.

```
Table[{i, x1[i], y1[i], x2[i], y2[i]}, {i, 0, 5.66, .001}] == 
    Table[{i, x1b[i], y1b[i], x2b[i], y2b[i]}, {i, 0, 5.66, .001}]
(* True *)
```

Furthermore, `Maximize` is unable to find any differences; e.g.,

```
Maximize[{Abs[x2[t] - x2b[t]], 0 < t < 5}, t]
(* {0., {t -> 0.71765}} *)
```

(I also have examined the `Line` instructions inside the `Plot`s, but they appear to yield no useful additional information.)

I can only conclude that whether `Plot` automatically can find discontinuities depends on details of the `InterpolatingFunction`s well outside the domain of the plot.  Further investigation of this issue appears to require information not generally available to Mathematica users.  Incidentally, the undesirable lines in the `ParametricPlot`s occur whenever they occur in the corresponding `Plot`s, and sometimes even when they do not occur in the corresponding `Plot`s.  Evidently, `ParametricPlot` has more difficulty identifying discontinuities than `Plot` does, which seems strange.

Comment: +1 for letting me use your simplified code. :)  You might be interested in my answer.