# Controlling precision/accuracy inside built-in commands

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy, built-in-symbols

Some functions (such as `Erf`) appear to use `NIntegrate` internally. In such cases, is there a way to control such options of `NIntegrate` as `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`?

**Edit in response to the comment by J.M.:** I did use such a command for numerical evaluation. The function of interest was `f[x_] = (x/((2 + x^2) Sqrt[1 + x^2]))InverseFunction[Erf][ArcTan[1/Sqrt[1 + x^2]] ]`. A calculation involving the values of `f[x]` and some of its derivatives of order `<=24` at `x` about `3.5 10^9` produced this message:

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy
>   after 9 recursive bisections in i near {i} = {150.979}. NIntegrate
>   obtained 0.0019560456659259958`and 7.756174544177548`*^-8 for the
>   integral and error estimates.

I thought that message probably concerned the function `Erf`, which is defined as a certain integral. If not `Erf`, it must then be `ArcTan` that triggered the NIntegrate::ncvb: message.

In any case, the essence of my question was as follows: Some built-in functions appear to use `NIntegrate` internally. In such cases, is there a way to control such options of `NIntegrate` as `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`?

Comment: No, `Erf[]` does not use `NIntegrate[]`. Just do `N[Erf[z], {prec, acc}]` if you must.

Comment: Solving sometimes uses `NIntegrate`.  Consider the message `Solve::nint`.  My guess is that it's `InverseFunction`.  Without code to reproduce the error, it might be impossible to say definitively.  I'm up to something like the 20th derivative of `f[x]` and still no errors.

Comment: `SetOptions` is the standard way. Sometimes they are set explicitly by the built-in function, and unfortunately you might not have a way to change it. Two examples in which I overrode behavior: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63676/4999, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120650/4999. A case where I failed, because the option setting is hard-coded internally: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95106/4999

Comment: @MichaelE2 : Thank you for your helpful comments. The entire code is, alas, too long to be reproduced here. In the first of the two examples you refer to, you knew that `Reduce` is an allowable value for `Method ->`. In general, is there a way to get the list of all such values for a given option? (Trying to learn more from you.)

Comment: For documented options & settings (such as `Reduce`), check the "Details and Options" section, as well as the "Options" subsection of the "Examples", in the documentation for the function (such as `Solve`).  For undocumented options & settings, some are listed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/809/how-can-one-find-undocumented-options-or-option-values-in-mathematica).

Comment: @MichaelE2 : Thank you. It seems that it's quite nontrivial to find information on undocumented options & settings.