# How to eliminate extraneous lines when using Mod within ParametricPlot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I've found two other similar questions:

[Plot of the Mod of NDSolve solutions sometimes connects discontinuous jumps](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94727/plot-of-the-mod-of-ndsolve-solutions-sometimes-connects-discontinuous-jumps/95106#95106)

and

[How can I remove horizontal lines on a phase plot for a pendulum?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78825/how-can-i-remove-horizontal-lines-on-a-phase-plot-for-a-pendulum/78877#78877)

Neither contains a solution to my problem, but in an answer to the first there is a tantalizing note: This seems to have been fixed in V11. Alas I'm running V11 and getting a very similar issue that I would *love* to get rid of. Here's my code:

```
Manipulate[
 Animate[sol = 
   NDSolve[{x'[t] == w1 + k1*Sin[y[t] - x[t]], 
     y'[t] == w2 + k2*Sin[x[t] - y[t]], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x, 
     y}, {t, 0, tmax}];
  ParametricPlot[Mod[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, 2 Pi], {t, 0, tplot}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {0, 2 Pi}}], {tplot, 0, tmax}],
 {{w1, 1}, -2, 2}, {{w2, 1}, -2, 2}, {{k1, 0.1}, 0, 2}, {{k2, 0.1}, 0,
   2}, {{x0, 0}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{y0, 0.2}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{tmax, 10}, 0, 100}
 ]
```

This is a simple coupled oscillator problem; the phase space is naturally the torus, i.e. the square with opposite edges identified. The obvious way to plot the solution then is Mod[], but we get the following:

[image]

The horizontal and vertical line shouldn't be there. I understand why they're added by ParametricPlot but I would like to get rid of them. I have tried using Exclusions; I have tried using WhenEvent within the NDSolve to reset x and y to zero so that the Mod[] is unnecessary and I get exactly the same output. Surely there's a solution? Perhaps ParametricPlot can be told to ignore jumps greater than $\varepsilon$? I don't need it to be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Animate[sol = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == w1 + k1*Sin[y[t] - x[t]], 
     y'[t] == w2 + k2*Sin[x[t] - y[t]], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x,  y}, {t, 0, tmax}];
  ParametricPlot[Mod[Through@sol@t, 2 Pi], {t, 0, tplot}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {0, 2 Pi}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   ImageSize -> 300], {tplot, 0, tmax}, Alignment -> Center], 
{{w1, 1}, -2, 2}, {{w2, 1}, -2, 2}, {{k1, 0.1}, 0, 2}, {{k2, 0.1}, 0, 2}, 
{{x0, 0}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{y0, 0.2}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{tmax, 10}, 0, 100}, 
Alignment -> Center, ContentSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can also use:

```
Manipulate[Animate[sol =  NDSolve[{x'[t] == w1 + k1*Sin[y[t] - x[t]], 
     y'[t] == w2 + k2*Sin[x[t] - y[t]], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}];
  m[t_] := Mod[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, 2 Pi]; 
  ParametricPlot[m[t], {t, 0, tplot}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {0, 2 Pi}}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {tplot, 0, tmax}], 
 {{w1, 1}, -2, 2}, {{w2, 1}, -2, 2}, {{k1, 0.1}, 0, 2}, {{k2, 0.1}, 0, 2}, 
 {{x0, 0}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{y0, 0.2}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{tmax, 10}, 0, 100}]
```

Comment: This works but I don't understand why. Is it the fact that you used NDSolveValue instead of NDSolve? If I add PerformanceGoal->"Quality" to my original example it doesn't fix the problem, so that can't be the whole story.

Comment: @dbx, I needed both.

Comment: @dbx, it turns out `NDSolveValue` is not necessary; if you define the function to be plotted outside `ParametricPlot`, that is, `m[t_] := Mod[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, 2 Pi]; ParametricPlot[m[t],...]` you get the  desired result.

Comment: Haha OK, thank you. This definitely answers the question, but... it raises some new ones!!

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you can use `ListPlot` instead of `ParametricPlot`

```
Manipulate[
 sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == w1 + k1*Sin[y[t] - x[t]], 
    y'[t] == w2 + k2*Sin[x[t] - y[t]], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x, 
    y}, {t, 0, tmax}]; Animate[
  ListPlot[
   Table[Mod[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol, 2 Pi], {t, 0, tplot, 0.05}], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {0, 2 Pi}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Tiny]}],
  {tplot, 0, tmax}], {{w1, 1}, -2, 2}, {{w2, 1}, -2, 2}, {{k1, 0.1}, 
  0, 2}, {{k2, 0.1}, 0, 2}, {{x0, 0}, 0, 2 Pi}, {{y0, 0.2}, 0, 
  2 Pi}, {{tmax, 10}, 0, 100}]
```

[image]